# Custom View in a Large UINavigationBar Using Constraints to the Limit Max Size

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating a custom view that I'm placing as a subview inside a UINavigationBar in the `viewDidLoad`. The intention is as the navigation bar resizes it changes the height of this view, but it won't expand past the height of the original navigation bar size when it was loaded. It's all working, except for it won't limit the height of the view.

How, can I get a constraint to limit the max height of the view to take precedence over the lead/trailing constraints?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar, let titleView = self.titleView {
        navigationBar.addSubview(titleView)

        let heightConstraint = titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: navigationBar.bounds.height)
        heightConstraint.priority = .required
        heightConstraint.isActive = true

        let topConstraint = titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.topAnchor)
        topConstraint.priority = .required
        topConstraint.isActive = true

        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[titleView]-0-|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["titleView": titleView])
        for constraint in horizontalConstraints {
            constraint.priority = .required
            constraint.isActive = true
        }

        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[titleView]-0-|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["titleView": titleView])
        for constraint in verticalConstraints {
            constraint.priority = .fittingSizeLevel
            constraint.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't the heightAnchor constraint not taking precedence?